# Naming convention of classification and prediction problem in case of hard disk failure

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, predictive-models

I wanted to classify the failure label of BlackBaze hard disk data. Response variable has binary labels $i.e$ $0$ for healthy and $1$ for failed drive. I am using binary classification models. However, I am confused with naming convention of this problem. Should I call it hard disk failure prediction or hard disk failure classification? I see some conflicting opinions regarding classification vs. prediction ([Link: Prof. Harrell's opinion](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/) ). Most hard disk domains named it as failure prediction although we are performing binary classification here which is confusing! I appreciate your suggestion!